# Angular Architecture

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services

Is the architecture used by the angular MVW, MVC or just a component-based architecture?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not in English

Comment: Give it the name you prefer, and move on. It doesn't matter. What matters is to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Angular2 is based on component architecture, where as each component will have MVC Architecture.
Each Component will have its Class(assume as Controller), View, Attributes of Class(assume as Model) are binded to view, thus it will follow MVC internally, and over view is Model-View-* we can say.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2+ uses Components instead of Controllers and it's architecture is often referred to as MVW (Model-View-Whatever) or MV*. For more information, you can read the following:

1. Official Angular documentation: https://angular.io/guide/architecture
2. Todd Motto's Presentation on Angular Architecture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vGKRKDPGUSs

Answer (score 0):

Angular 5 and above uses MVVM architecture internally.The model contains the business end of your application and you have to use services for that purpose so that the business logic is separate from view.The view contains the template that is html and css.
The View-Model lies in the .ts files of the components.The View-Model has no knowledge of the View but provides a Model-like API that can be used by the View.

for more information about angular and related topics

https://medium.com/webskill